# Open Fancybox from Fancybox and close parent

Tags: fancybox

I have fancybox trouble. My product is opening in fancybox and I have related products withtin content. I would like to close fancybox when user clicks on related link and open product in new fancybox.

Thank you guys for your help. But it is not working :( . Product opens in a window without fancybox.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("a#fancy1").fancybox({
        'speedIn'           : 600, 
        'speedOut'          : 200, 
        'overlayShow'       : false,
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : 620,
        'height'            : 'auto',
        'overlayShow'       : true,
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
        'overlayColor'      : '#ccc'
});
$("a#fancy2").fancybox({
        'speedIn'           : 600, 
        'speedOut'          : 200, 
        'overlayShow'       : false,
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : 620,
        'height'            : 'auto',
        'overlayShow'       : true,
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
        'overlayColor'      : '#ccc'
}); 
});
```

This what I have. Clicking on the product opens fancybox "fancy1". But Clicking within fancybox link opens related product without fancy and I'm getting:

(**$ is not defined $(function(){$('#form_2538').validate();});**) !

Linking to a product done this way

```
<a id="fancy1" href="product_url" >
```

Linking to a related done this way

```
<a id="fancy2" href="product_url" >
```

I have been struggling with this for a while :(

AND I HAVE RESOLVED IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I have resolved issue!!

Please see below!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("a.fancy1").live("hover",
        function()
        {$("a.fancy1").fancybox({
        'speedIn'           : 600, 
        'speedOut'          : 200, 
        'overlayShow'       : false,
        'autoDimensions'    : false,
        'width'             : 620,
        'height'            : 'auto',
        'overlayShow'       : true,
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
        'overlayColor'      : '#ccc'

        });
        });
    });
```

Comment: this error `($ is not defined $(function(){$('#form_2538').validate();});)` seems to be unrelated to fancybox and it might be broken the fancybox script as well. Check your validation script settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to bind fancybox for each link separately like

```
$("a#fancy1").fancybox({
// options
});
$("a#fancy2").fancybox({
// options
});
```

Notice that the second script is not inside of the first one (`onClosed` option).

Open the first fancybox like:

```
<a id="fancy1" href="{link to product}">open product</a>
```

Then inside the opened content you should have a link like

```
<a id="fancy2" href="{target to related product}">see related product</a>
```

you don't actually have to close the first fancybox, linking to the second from inside of it will close it.

Comment: as you can see in example above I have followed your suggestion and still not getting any result. Sad.

Comment: Thank you JFK. Your solution kind of worked. I had to use 

$("a#fancy1").fancybox({
// options
}); 
$("a#fancy1").fancybox({
// options
});
TWICE!
But! Opening product with fancybox and clicking on related product within it works only 1 time. If I open related product which got a related products too, it doesnt work..

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="product_url" id="fancy2">Link</a>

<script>
$('#fancy2').click(function()
{
    $(this).parent().fancybox.close();
});
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
$('#fancy2').click(function()
{
    $('a#fancy1').trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm a bit new to js. Didn't get it! Where do I put it? Like so: ?

Comment: Well you need to pace code in $(document).ready(function() { /*place code herer */ });

Comment: and I guess you need to do this for each link?

$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).fancybox({
   // options  
   });
});