# FancyBox how can I close active fancybox when link is clicked and open another fancybox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I already have this to close the active fancybox:

```
javascript:parent.$.fancybox.close();
```

added to my link.

Question : how can I open another fancybox content when that link is clicked?

Say: I have the login form open via fancybox. There is a link which says: Do not have an account. So if that link is clicked I want to load registration form and close login form. What is best practice to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be a few other questions around on this subject.
This one for example:
[How do I open one Fancybox after another closes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715986/how-do-i-open-one-fancybox-after-another-closes)

Answer (score 0):

Another and simpler way to do it without using callbacks here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10694032/1055987.

Actually that covers the latest 1.3.x version of fancybox while the [other question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1715986/1055987) was written for a much older version.